# Subscripts in high level Lattice graphing call

Tags: r, lattice

For data frame df.test with five columns:

```
df.test <- data.frame(

dt=c('2011-01-01','2011-01-01','2011-01-02','2011-01-02'),
q1=c(1,99,99,1),
q5=c(5,95,95,5),
q50=c(50,50,50,50), 
test=c(74,72,72,74)

)
```

Can someone explain why running the print() function on subscripts returns an index for four columns c(1,2,3,4) and not an index for five columns c(1,2,3,4,5)?

```
xyplot(q1 ~ as.POSIXct(dt), data=df.test,
 panel = function(x, y, subscripts) { 
  print(subscripts)
 }
)
```

I've read the entire lattice documentation, but not the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `subscripts` here refers to the row indices. Since you have no grouping variable, this will just include all of the original rows 1:4.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
> xyplot(q1 ~ as.POSIXct(dt)|test, data=df.test,
+  panel = function(x, y, subscripts) { 
+   print(subscripts)
+  }
+ )
[1] 2 3
[1] 1 4
```